# jQuery if statement causes browser to crash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small script that should show a hidden div if the corresponding button is pressed. For example, if the button first-button is clicked than the div first-button-content should show. Right now, when I click on the button, chrome crashes and the div does not show.

Here is the html:

```
    <div class="home-middle-buttons">
        <div class="first-button">
            <span>I’m an In-House Marketer</span>
        </div>
        <div class="second-button">
            <span>I Work at an Agency</span>
        </div>
        <div class="third-button">
            <span>I’m a Business Owner</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-middle-content">
        <div class="first-button-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </div>

        <div class="second-button-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </div>

        <div class="third-button-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".home-middle-buttons div").click(function() {
        if (jQuery(".first-button").click()) {
            jQuery(".first-button-content").css( 'display', 'block' );
        } else {
            jQuery(".second-button-content").css( 'display', 'block' );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Only Chrome crashes? 0_0

Comment: Firefox does not crash. It shows "too much recursion" in the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
if (jQuery(".first-button").click()) {
```

Calling `.click()` actually *triggers* a click event, it doesn't test if a click has occurred. So then that in turn calls your click handler, which gets to that line and triggers a click, which calls the handler, etc.

Try this:

```
if (jQuery(this).hasClass("first-button")) {
```

Within your click handler, `this` refers to the particular button that was clicked, and jQuery's `.hasClass()` returns a boolean for whether the element has that class.

But a nicer way to set the whole thing up would be as follows:

```
<div class="home-middle-buttons">
    <div data-associated-content="first-button-content">
        <span>I’m an In-House Marketer</span>
    </div>
    <div data-associated-content="second-button-content">
        <span>I Work at an Agency</span>
    </div>
    <div data-associated-content="third-button-content">
        <span>I’m a Business Owner</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="home-middle-content">
    <!-- as in the question -->
</div>
```

With this JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".home-middle-buttons div").click(function() {
        var associatedDiv = jQuery(this).attr("data-associated-content");
        jQuery("." + associatedDiv).show();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uHzTB/

Note: if `data-associated-content` seems kind of long feel free to use `data-something-shorter`. Also, the classes on your content divs seem to uniquely identify those divs so I'd suggest that it would be more logical to make them an `id` rather than a `class`.

Comment: Spectacular. Thanks for the help. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. I can't for another eight minutes.

Comment: `jQuery(this).data("associated-content");` would work the same, no?

Comment: @acdcjunior - Depends on your definition of "better". I tend not to use `.data()` to retrieve attribute values because (although it doesn't matter in this case) it tries to do data type conversion, and also I prefer to make it clear the value I'm using is from an element attribute rather than a value previously set with `.data()`.

Answer (score 5):

Because you have kind of recursive function call , this line is problematic:

```
if (jQuery(".first-button").click()) {
```

it calls this:

```
jQuery(".home-middle-buttons div").click(function() {
```

and this calls the first again, so it is recursive

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> jQuery(".first-button").click()
> ```

Now, that's not how you get the clicked element. Instead, it is a shortcut for [`.trigger("click")`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) - you basically are creating an infinite loop by firing the event handler again and again.

Instead, you want to test the current element - [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) - whether it [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) the first button:

```
$(this).is(".first-button")
```

You might as well use the [`hasClass` method](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).